# Regular expression to allow either 6 digit or 10 digit with a symbol (-)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to validate a text in text box using regex code where user will be allowed to either 6 digit or 10 digit with a symbol(-) any where between the digits for zip code I am able t achieve the digit limitation using `/^(\d{6}|\d{10})$/` but not able to apply an optional symbol

Can some one please help me to short this out.

Comment: please add some examples.

Comment: Sounds pretty clear. 1-12345, 12-1234, 123-123 and so on

Comment: is it possible to achieve in this format "12345-1234"  ? http://jsfiddle.net/5PNcJ/238/

Comment: I was finding it a little tricky to write a regex for this. In lieu of someone smarter coming along, perhaps you could run `replace('-', '');` on the string and match with `/(\d{6}(\d{4})?)/`? So `str.replace('-', '').test('/(\d{6}(\d{4})?)/');`

Comment: Is the dash `-` mandatory or optional?

Answer (score 1):

You could check first the wanted length and then the content.

```
/^                                 string start
  (?=(.{7}|.{11})$)                length check with positive look ahead
                   \d+-\d+         pattern check
                          $/       end of string
```

```js
var test = [
        '1',
        'a',
        '-',
        '12',
        '1245678901234567',
        '1-23456',
        '12-3456',
        '123-456',
        '1234-56',
        '12345-6',
        '12-345-6',
        '12345-67890',
        'foo-bar'
    ];

test.forEach(function (a) {
    console.log(a, /^(?=(.{7}|.{11})$)\d+-\d+$/.test(a));
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex makes the dash optional:

```js
var test = [
        '12456789',
        '12345678901',
        '123456',
        '1234567890',
        '1-23456',
        '12-34567890',
    ];

console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' : '+/^(?:(?:(?=.{7}$|.{11}$)\d+-\d+)|\d{6}|\d{10})$/.test(a);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @vickey comment ,it achieve his format "12345-1234"

```
[0-9]{1,5}-[0-9]{1,4}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5PNcJ/239/

Comment: Did you try it? It matches `1234567-` that is not wanted but doesn't match `1-23456` that is wanted.

Comment: Now it matches `12-34`, it also matches `abcd1234567891234567889-0000000000jhqgdfkjhjhfdgfkqjgmoieu`

Comment: @Toto , check this regex express. on http://regexr.com/ ,then you will get know why its  matches.